# Adding a new element to arraylist only when a limit is reached

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to write a receive() method for a warehouse class but is not displaying the result I want. The main method is this:

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    Warehouse w = new Warehouse( 10 ); 
    Footwear d0 = new DressShoe( "Loafer", 10.5, "1234-13" ); 
    Footwear b = new Boot( "Riding", 8, "1234-5" ); 
    Footwear c = new CasualShoe( "Sandal", 9.5, "1234-0" ); 
    Footwear d1 = new DressShoe( "Wing-tip", 10, "1234-3" ); 
    w.receive( d0, 4 ); 
    w.receive( b, 25 ); 
    w.receive( c, 18 ); 
    w.receive( d1, 5 ); 
    System.out.println(w);
}
```

I want the it to print this where each Bin should only have total quantity of 10 (quantity is the number farthest right).

```
Bin B0:
Dress Shoe – Loafer (size 10½), SKU 1234-13: 4
Casual Shoe – Sandal (size 9½), SKU 1234-0: 6
Bin B1:
Boot – Riding (size 8), SKU 1234-5: 10
Bin B2:
Boot – Riding (size 8), SKU 1234-5: 10
Bin B3:
Boot – Riding (size 8), SKU 1234-5: 5
Casual Shoe – Sandal (size 9½), SKU 1234-0: 2
Dress Shoe – Wing-tip (size 10), SKU 1234-3: 3
Bin B4:
Casual Shoe – Sandal (size 9½), SKU 1234-0: 10
Bin B5:
Dress Shoe – Wing-tip (size 10), SKU 1234-3: 2
```

but mine doesn't print any other than "Dress Shoe – Loafer (size 10½)" and it won't create a new Bin when the total quantity is 10. Mine just looks like

```
Bin B0:
Dress Shoe - Loafer (size 10½), SKU 1234-13: 52
Bin B1:
Dress Shoe - Loafer (size 10½), SKU 1234-13: 48
Bin B2:
Dress Shoe - Loafer (size 10½), SKU 1234-13: 23
Bin B3:
Dress Shoe - Loafer (size 10½), SKU 1234-13: 5
Bin B4:
```

These are my classes so far.

```
public class Warehouse
{
private int myBinMax;
private ArrayList<Footwear> myCatalog;
private ArrayList<Bin> myBins;

public Warehouse(int binMax)
{
    myBinMax = binMax;
    myCatalog = new ArrayList<Footwear>();
    myBins = new ArrayList<Bin>(5);
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        addBin();
    }
}
public void addBin()
{
    myBins.add( new Bin( "B" + myBins.size() ) );
}
public String toString()
{
    String s = "";
    for ( Bin bin : myBins )
    {
        s += "Bin " + bin.getName() + ":\n";
        for (int i = 0; i < bin.getContents().size(); i++) {
            s += Lab04Runner.lookupFootwear(myCatalog, 
          bin.getContents().get(i).getSKU()) + ", " + 
          bin.getContents().get(i) + "\n";
        }
    }
    return s;
}
public void receive(Footwear object, int a)
{
    if (!myCatalog.contains(object))
    {
        myCatalog.add(object);
    }
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    String name;
    for (Bin bin : myBins)
    {
        for( int i =0; i<myCatalog.size(); i++)
        {
        if (bin.totalQuantity() < min)
        {
            if (bin.totalQuantity() == 0)
            {
                min = 0;
                name = bin.getName();
                BinItem bi = new BinItem(myCatalog.get(i).getSKU(), a);    
                bin.add(bi);
            }
            else
            {
                min = bin.totalQuantity();
                name = bin.getName();
                BinItem bi = new BinItem(myCatalog.get(i).getSKU(), a);    
                bin.add(bi);
            }
            if (bin.totalQuantity() == myBinMax)
            {
                addBin();
                name = myBins.get(myBins.size() - 1).getName();
                BinItem bi = new BinItem( myCatalog.get(i).getSKU(), 
                  a);
                myBins.get(myBins.size()-1).add(bi);
            }
        }
    }
    }
}
}

public class Lab04Runner
{
public static String lookupFootwear( ArrayList<Footwear> catalog, 
String sku )
{
    int n = Integer.parseInt(sku.replace("-", ""));
    for ( Footwear fw : catalog )
    {
        if (n <= 123499 && n >= 12340)
        {
            return "" + fw;
        }
    }

    return "SKU " + sku + " not in catalog";
}

public class Footwear
{
private String myStyle;
private double mySize;
private String mySKU;
public Footwear(String s, double r, String k)
{
    myStyle = s;
    mySize = r;
    mySKU = k;
}
public String getStyle()
{
    return myStyle;
}
public double getSize()
{
    return mySize;
}
public String getSKU()
{
    return mySKU;
}
public String getType()
{
    return "Unspecified";
}
public String printSize()
{
    if (mySize - (int)mySize == 0)
    {
        return "" +(int)mySize;
    }
    else
    {
        return "" +(int)mySize + "\u00bd";
    }
}    
public String toString()
{
    return getType() + " - " + getStyle() + " (size " + printSize() + 
")";
}
public class Bin
{
private String myName;
private ArrayList<BinItem> myContents;

public Bin( String name )
{
    myName = name;
    myContents = new ArrayList<BinItem>();
}
public String getName() 
{
    return myName; 
}
public ArrayList<BinItem> getContents()
{
    return myContents;
}
public void remove( int i )
{
    myContents.remove( i );
}
public int totalQuantity()
{
    int total = 0;
    for ( BinItem b : myContents )
    {
        total += b.getQuantity();
    }
    return total;
}
public void add( BinItem b )
{
    String sku = b.getSKU();
    int n = b.getQuantity();
    BinItem item;
    for ( int i = 0; i < myContents.size(); i++ )
    {
        item = myContents.get( i );
        if ( sku.equals( item.getSKU() ) )
        {
            int m = item.getQuantity();
            myContents.remove( i );
            myContents.add( new BinItem( sku, m+n ) );
            return;
        }
    }

    myContents.add( b );
}
public String toString()
{
    String s = "Bin " + myName + ":";
    for ( BinItem b : myContents )
    {
        s += "\n" + b;
    }
    return s;
}
public class BinItem
{
private String mySKU;
private int myQuantity;

public BinItem(String sku, int quantity)
{
    mySKU = sku;
    myQuantity = quantity;
}

public String getSKU()
{
    return mySKU;
}

public int getQuantity()
{
    return myQuantity;
}

public String toString()
{
    return "SKU " + getSKU() + ": " + getQuantity();
}  
}
```

How would I stop it from adding and instead add a new element to the arraylist? Also how do I get it to print the other objects and not just the first one?

Answer (score 0):

You are not calucalting the remaining items that can be put into your Bin. You always add all items. So a solution would be to add the items equally to the existing bins. When there are still items left you have to add another bin and call the receive method again to add the remaining items to the new bin.

```
public void receive(Footwear object, int a) {
    if (!myCatalog.contains(object)) {
        myCatalog.add(object);
    }
    int amountOfRemainingItems = 0;
    amountOfRemainingItems = distributeEqually(object, a);
    if(amountOfRemainingItems > 0) {
        addBin();
        receive(object, amountOfRemainingItems);
    }
}

private int distributeEqually(Footwear object, int amountOfRemainingItems) {
    for (Bin bin : myBins) {
        if(amountOfRemainingItems == 0) {
            break;
        }
        if (bin.totalQuantity() < myBinMax) {
            int itemsToAdd = calculateItemsToAdd(bin, amountOfRemainingItems);
            amountOfRemainingItems -= itemsToAdd;
            BinItem bi = new BinItem(object.getSKU(), itemsToAdd);
            bin.add(bi);
        } 
    }
    return amountOfRemainingItems;
}

private int calculateItemsToAdd(Bin bin, int amountOfremainingItems) {
    return (myBinMax - bin.totalQuantity()) >= amountOfremainingItems ? amountOfremainingItems : 
        myBinMax - bin.totalQuantity();
}
```

I think there may be a better solution that is a bit faster, because you iterate over all bins every time. But it could be a first solution on which you could build up.